# Chrome thinks my desktop computer is a touch device?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, modernizr

Spontaneously, for myself and my coworkers, Modernizr has started telling us that we're on touch devices when we're *very much not on touch devices.*

Why is this happening to all of us? Has anyone else seen this? Google turned up nothing. How can I fix it?